# How to generate an El Gamal signature without knowing the private key x?

Tags: attack, elgamal-signature

Let $x$ be the private key.
Let $k$ be a random generated number $< p-1$, with $p$ the large prime.
Let $g$ be the generator of $p$ the large prime.
Let $r$ be the equality $r=g^k$
Let $m_e$ be an oridnary message.
Let $s$ be the signature $s=k^{-1}[m-rx] \bmod p-1$

My question is, how do we generate a valid signature $s'$ without knowing the private key $x$? The only indication I have is writing down the equality $r$ as a product $g^a\cdot y^b$ with $y=g^x$.

P.S: I don't remember how to format, so sorry if things are a little bit messy.